# how to get pthread_mutex_lock() to block instead of succeeding?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I thought I knew C and mutexes... apparently I don't.

The following code, I would expect to print the address, wait 5 seconds, then print the same address again.

It does not - it prints the same address twice, but immediately, why??

I compile the code with

```
>gcc -lpthread foobar.c
```

I must be not understanding something obvious, it is embarrasing...

After advice from Jonathan Leffler and Chris Dodd and user3629249, I have edited the code as below, same problem.  This is getting really embarrasing...

foobar.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void foobar(pthread_mutex_t *plock) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(plock);
    printf("lock address %p\n", plock);
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(5);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(plock);
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_mutex_t *plock;
    pthread_mutexattr_t attr;

    pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
    printf("return %d\n", pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED));
    printf("mutex allocated %p\n", plock = malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)));
    printf("return %d\n", pthread_mutex_init(plock, &attr));
    fork() ? foobar(plock) : foobar(plock);
}
```

Comment: Where is the mutex initialized?  PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER? [`pthread_mutex_init()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler good point, thank you - but I am still having the same problem

Comment: @caf the above call fails, returns -1

Comment: @caf ... still returns -1  feel free to tell me to debug this myself, I probably should

Comment: @caf yes now it works.  thank you.  Chris's answer is IMHO incomplete, I would prefer to accept a complete answer.

Comment: I've edited that answer to add the code I gave in a comment (and removed the comments).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pthread mutexes are for synchonizing *threads* within a single *process*.  When you call `fork`, it creates a new *process* with a copy of all the parent process's resources.

So in this case, there are TWO INDEPENDENT mutexes, one in the parent process and one in the child.  The inital state of the mutex in the child is copied from the parent, but since that state is unlocked, that's just a new unlocked mutex.

Then the parent and child both acquire their own mutex and continue.

If you were to change your code to call `pthread_create` instead of `fork`, it would work more like you are (apparently) expecting.

Note that it is *possible* to use pthread mutexes between threads in different processes -- if you create the mutex in a shared memory space that is shared by the processes and use the appropriate `PROCESS_SHARED` attributes.

To create the mutex in shared memory, you can replace your `malloc()` call with:

```
plock = mmap(NULL, (sizeof *plock + 4095) & ~4095UL, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0)
```

(The `4095` value here should really be one less than the system page size, `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) - 1`)

Comment: thank you, but I am trying to synchronize between processes, not threads...  I do need to use `fork()`

Answer (score 1):

this link: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared.html

says this about using a mutex across processes:

```
#include <pthread.h>

...

pthread_mutex_t * pmutex = NULL;
pthread_mutexattr_t attrmutex;

/* Initialise attribute to mutex. */
pthread_mutexattr_init(&attrmutex);
pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&attrmutex, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

/* Allocate memory to pmutex here. */

/* Initialise mutex. */
pthread_mutex_init(pmutex, &attrmutex);

/* Use the mutex. */

/* Clean up. */
pthread_mutex_destroy(pmutex);
pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&attrmutex);
```

and this link: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_condattr_setpshared.html

describes how to signal across processes like so:

```
#include <pthread.h>

...

pthread_cond_t * pcond = NULL;
pthread_condattr_t attrcond;

/* Initialise attribute to condition. */
pthread_condattr_init(&attrcond);
pthread_condattr_setpshared(&attrcond, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);

/* Allocate memory to pcond here. */

/* Initialise condition. */
pthread_cond_init(pcond, &attrcond);

/* Use the condition. */

/* Clean up. */
pthread_cond_destroy(pcond);
pthread_condattr_destroy(&attrcond);
```